# Rename images keeping the old name and adding prefix which corresponds to the order of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list
`List=["cat", "dog", "horse", "",...]`
and  I have images in `./images/folder/` which contains images files:

```
image0.png
image100.png
image2.png
...
```

Note images are not ordered in folder and os.listdir(path) show:

```
'image118.png'
'image124.png'
'image130.png'
...
```

My expectation is to receive files with these names.

```
image0_cat.png
image1_dog.png
image2_horse.png
...
```

This is my current code:

```py
    import os
    path= './images/folder/'
    
    for label, filename in zip(my_label,os.listdir(path)):
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            os.rename(path + "/" +filename, path + "/" +filename + "_" + str(label) + ".png")
```

But the output is different than my expectations.

Output:

```
image0.png_horse.png
image1OO.png_horse.png
image2.png_cat.png
...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the name of the images is always `image<nb>.png`, with  ranging from 1 to `len(my_label)` without interruptions then you can generate the names directly instead of scanning through the folder:

```py
for i, label in enumerate(my_label):
    filename = f"image{i+1}"
    old_file = os.path.join(path, filename + ".png")
    new_file = os.path.join(path, filename + f"_{label}.png")
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

where `os.path.join` is the preferred way to actually generate file paths (it takes into account the "/", and different OS systems)

Otherwise, you will need to first parse the numbers from the list of files:

```py
numbers = []
for image in os.listdir(path):
    number = os.path.basename(image)[len("image"):-len(".png")]
    numbers.append(int(number))
```

then you can sort that list:

```py
sorted_numbers = sorted(numbers)
```

And finally, you can iterate through that list, to generate the filenames (that you know should exist), similarly to the previous method:

```py
for number, label in zip(sorted_numbers, my_label):
    filename = f"image{number}"
    old_file = os.path.join(path, filename + ".png")
    new_file = os.path.join(path, filename + f"_{label}.png")
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Assuming that you have the right number of labels for your images.

Comment: Thank you FlorentMONIN for your reply and for your help. I don't have the possibility to vote your answer but I confirmed it.                                                                   
The second code worked fine , for the first one  it started renamed the images from second image image1.png and not image0.png so there is a lag and at the end he did not find the last image filename = f"image{i+1}" it work with filename = f"image{i}"

Comment: You’re welcome! Yes, I assumed it would start at one and not 0, but if it does start at 0 then you indeed just need to change the {i+1} to {i}

Answer (score 0):

Use `filename.split(".")[0]` to get the root of your filename. Inside your code it would be

```py
for label, filename in zip(my_label,os.listdir(path)):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        name = filename.split(".")[0]
        os.rename(path + "/" + filename, path + "/" + name + "_" + str(label) + ".png")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

path = './images/folder/'
my_label = ["cat", "dog", "horse", "",...]

for label, filename in zip(my_label, os.listdir(path)):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        fn = Path(filename)
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename),os.path.join(path, f"{fn.stem}_{label}{fn.suffix}"))
```

This code is little more universal because you use original extension instead hardcoded ".png". You can read more about pathlib here: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)